# How to turn a number into a decimal in Sass

Tags: css, sass

wondering how to make the . outside of the $value

```
@mixin opacity($value) {
    opacity: .$value;
}
```

How escape that dot `.`?  I want this:

```
.foo {
    @include opacity(3);
}
```

To generate this:

```
.foo {
    opacity: .3;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use division.  Using string interpolation just gives you a string, which is unsuitable for passing to Sass functions that expect numbers:

```
@mixin opacity($value) {
    opacity: $value / 10;
}

.foo {
    background-color: rgba(5, 5, 5, $value / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like this:

```
@mixin opacity($value){
  opacity: unquote('.#{$value}');
}
```

Comment: Thanks how about background-color with opacity? `background-color: rgba(5,5, 5, unquote('.#{$value}'));`